# What is the breakpoint of a piecewise function?

Tags: limits, functions

For

$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & x\leq -1\\ 
  \sqrt{1-x^2},& -1 < x < 1 \\ 
x, & x\geq 1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

My book says that the breakpoints are x = -1 and x = 1. How breakpoints are defined so that -1 and 1 is chosen?

Comment: How does the book define "breakpoint"?

Comment: I am only at the first chapter where it is introduced as "The formula for f changes at the points x = −1 and x = 1. (We call these the
breakpoints for the formula.) ". There are dedicated chapters for limits which I have not reached yet, from other online sources it looks like breakpoint is related with the idea of limit.

Comment: I would understand a "breakpoint" of a function $f(x)$ to be a location $x_b$ where the **first derivative** $f'(x_b)$ is disontinuous, i.e. where $f'(x)$ "jumps", mathematically, where the limits of $f'(x)$ for $x\to x_b$ from below is different from that from above.

Comment: OK, so it's the *formula* that has breakpoints.  The parenthetical remark is introducing the terminology; in effect, it *is* the definition.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze, the formula $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,\quad x\le0\\e^{-1/x}\quad x\gt0\end{cases}$$ has a breakpoint at $x=0$, even though the function has derivatives of *all* orders.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra  It's the *function* rather than the *formula*. The graph of the function has a kink in the breakpoint.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze, the passage that the OP quotes from their book talks about the *formula* having breakpoints, not the function.

Comment: Ok, matter of definition in the book, of course. To my taste I'd like to see something break, i.e. a kink in the graph ... In the formula it's just a point of transition from one piece to the other. Please refer also to the formulation of the question in the OP and/or see http://eaton.math.rpi.edu/cplex90html/usrcplex/usingPiecewiseLin3.html

Answer (score 2):

"Break points" are where the graph "breaks"- where the graph is no longer continuous or is not "smooth".  Basically that means where the "formula" for the function changes so that you need a "piecewise" definition.

Comment: But how break point is mathematically defined? How can I get the breakpoints of a given function if there is any?

Comment: @user247327 I worry that your definition would not include where $x=-1$ as both pieces of the function $=0$ there, so it would be continuous.

Comment: Don't worry!  I **said** "or is not smooth".  The derivative of f(x)= 0 is 0 while the derivative of $f(x)= \sqrt{1- x^2}$ is $-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1- x^2}}$ which does not exist at x= -1.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is defined *piecewise*. The break points are wherever one of the pieces ends and the next begins. Here, the first piece is defined for $x\leq -1$, so this piece ends and $x=-1$, and the next piece is defined for $-1<x<1$, so this piece ends at $x=1$.

You could then say that the break points are where the function is broken into its constituent parts.